# What's the pythonic way to add a certain character after every X elements of a list?

Tags: python, list

In my case, I want to add `\n` after every 5 words of a list. For example:

Input:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', 'kk']
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', '\n', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', '\n', 'kk']
```

My solution is intuitive but doesn't look concise and pythonic, so I'd like to hear your ideas.

```
def get_text(input):
    output = []
    for idx, w in enumerate(input):
        output.append(w)
        if idx !=0 and idx %4 == 0:
            output.append('\n')
    return output
```

Comment: Your solution is easy to read and understand, why are you not happy with it?

Comment: thanks, I was looking for something more concise, like one line code that solves the problem.

Comment: You certainl CAN strap that into a one liner, but the big question is - why? It will not be as clear as this couple-line formatting. As interesting thing, go into python interpreter and type "import this" ;)

Comment: haha, I like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this input:

```
lst = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', 'kk']
```

Try this, as a one-liner (assuming Python 2.x):

```
sum([lst[i:i+5]+['\n'] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 5)], [])[:-1]
```

Or in two lines, but more efficient:

```
tmp = (lst[i:i+5]+['\n'] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 5))
[item for slist in tmp for item in slist][:-1]
```

Either way, the result is as expected:

```
=> ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', '\n',
    'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', '\n',
    'kk']
```